# Import joomla to wordpress FAQ schema

Tags: wordpress, joomla, schema

We plan to move our site from Joomla to WordPress

We will do a database to database transfer of posts and pages.

We have more than 3000 pages on our Joomla site

More than 1000 pages use FAQ and how to schema

Is there a way to programmatically convert the how-to and faq schema of Joomla to WordPress?

Comment: What do you mean by how-to and faq schema? It is not a feature of Joomla, possibly you implemented it with Fields? If so, from what I gather of the Wordpress taxonomies, you're in for a week for coding.

Comment: @RiccardoZorn I am Structured Data by Google https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/faqpage

Comment: yes, but did you manually input the markup in the editor, or did you use an extension?